# Django 2.1.7 How to use a decorator on a package view

Tags: python, django, decorator, django-allauth

I would like to know how to use a decorator on a function view.py which do not find it directly in my application, but in a pakage (venv / lib / ...)

For more details, I'm going to build an application that uses django-allauth.
I create a decorator that asks the user to confirm their password before accessing certain page.

All goes well but I would like to use this constructor on the function of aullauth that can manage emails.

I do not know how to proceed...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igX1s.jpg)

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a fucntion view you can do this

```
import package_view...

@decorator
def custom_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return package_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If it is a CBV you can inherit from it and add a decorator to the dispatch method:

```
class CustomView(PackageView):
    @decorator
    def dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: After having a better look at the package, this is a class.

But it's interesting to know that for the function. ;) Thanks

Comment: I added the solution for a CBV

Comment: @ChrisPro You are welcome, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Pedro So here I have tried the solution for Class Base Views, but it did not work.
As my knowledge is limited I probably did not target the right class ...

Nevertheless, I solved the problem by targeting the url and using the decorator on the targeted url

Here's what it looks like if it can help other people:

```
...
from allauth.account import views as allauth_views
from .decorators import confirm_password

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    re_path(r"^email/$", confirm_password(allauth_views.email), name="account_email"), 
    ...
]
```

Thank you very much, I am grateful for your help and time.

It is very likely that your solutions will help me in the future. :)